# How to list all tags for every docker image present in catalog?

Tags: bash, shell, while-loop, sh, jq

I am using the following command to list all the images within my private registry:

```
curl -s http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[0:2] | to_entries | map( .value )[]'
```

Output:

```
centos
containersol/consul-server
```

I am using the following command to list all the tags of a particular image within my private registry:

```
 curl -s GET http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/centos/tags/list | jq -r '.tags | to_entries | map( .value )[]'
```

Output:

```
6.6
6
7.1.1503
```

Now, I am trying to list all tags for every image present in catalog using the following bash script:

```
#!/bin/sh

image_name=$(curl -s http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/_catalog | jq -r '.repositories[0:2] | to_entries | map( .value )[]')

while read -r line; do 
    ${line}$_image_taglist=$(curl -s GET http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/cybs/${line}/tags/list | jq -r '.tags | to_entries | map( .value )[]')
    while read -r tag; do
        echo "$tag"
     done <<< "${line}$_image_taglist"  
done <<< "$image_name"
```

However, I am getting the following error while executing `${line}$_image_taglist=$(curl -s GET http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/cybs/${line}/tags/list | jq -r '.tags | to_entries | map( .value )[]')` :

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:1): null (null) has no keys
```

Also, please note that I am expecting that `dynamic variable` `${line}$_image_taglist` should resolve to `centos_image_taglist` and `containersol/consul-server_image_taglist`

Comment: Could you provide a sample of the input json?

Comment: Also, can you specify which of the two jq invocations is producing this error? You can write "set -x" at the beginning of your script (below the hashbang) to see each line being printed.

Comment: @JeffMercado  I have provided more details in my original post.

Comment: No, don't show us the results of passing your json through jq, show us the json itself, for all invocations.

Comment: `${line}$_image_taglist=whatever` is a syntax error. What exactly are you trying to accomplish here? You are using Bash constructs anyway (the `<<<` here-string is not supported in `sh` generally) so my guess would be you want to use Bash arrays.  But the inner `while read` looks completely wacky, too. If you want to split a collection of fields, try `printf "%s\n" $string_with_many_whitespace_fields` (but this is a very vague guess; your code doesn't really do that, either).

Comment: FYI `| to_entries | map( .value )` is a [NOP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NOP) and can be omitted: `.repositories[0:2][]`

Comment: Post the output of `http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/cybs/${line}/tags/list`, actually you don't need to since it's `null`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> jq: error (at :1): null (null) has no keys

Is caused by `.` being null. In this case `.` refers to stdin which means that you get no response from `http://internal.private.registry.com/v2/cybs/${line}/tags/list`.

You cannot define dynamic named variables like this: `${line}$_image_taglist`. You should use an associative array if your bash version supports it:

```
declare -A arr
arr["$line"]=$(curl ... | jq ...)
```

But in your case I can't really see why you need it, since you are just iteration over it. Why not use a pipe or process substitution?

```
while read -r tag; do
    echo "$tag"
 done < <(curl ... | jq ...)
```